# Как я могу удалить элемент списка содержащий определённый символ

Tags: python

Например есть список str:

```
genre  = ['Жанр:', 'Слэшер', 'Шутер', 'Хоррор', 'РПГ', 'Аркада']
```

Как мне найти тот элемент в котором содержится ":" и удалить его?

Comment: Варианты: 1) Создать новый список, исключив из него те элементы, что не подходят 2) Пройтись по списку и удалить по элементам или по индексам неподходящие элементы

Comment: Оффтоп. Список похож на работу какого-нибудь парсера, мб парсер подкрутить, чтобы он не захватывал такие поля? :)

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю такое решение:

```
genres = ['Жанр:', 'Слэшер', 'Шутер', 'Хоррор', 'РПГ', 'Аркада']

filter_genres = [genre for genre in genres if ':' not in genre]

print(filter_genres) # ['Слэшер', 'Шутер', 'Хоррор', 'РПГ', 'Аркада']
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код у меня работает:

```py
genre  = ['Жанр:', 'Слэшер', 'Шутер', 'Хоррор', 'РПГ', 'Аркада']

removed = []

for i, g in enumerate(genre):
    if ":" in g:
        removed.append(g)

for r in removed:
    genre.remove(r)
```

Comment: Второй цикл не нужен. Да и if в нём - вероятно, тоже.

Answer (score 0):

могу предложить еще вот такой вариант

```
[genre.remove(a) for a in genre if a.count(':') > 0]
```

или немного другой

```
[genre.remove(a) for a in genre if ':' in a]
```

или третий вариант

```
[genre.remove(a) for a in genre for letter in a if letter == ':']
```

Comment: Неправильно же...